Difficulty Understanding the Concept of "Measures"
I am self-studying topics in probability (I am in mechanical engineering) and I have been able to get by without having to fully understand the concept of "Measures". I tried reading about them and watching videos on the internet, and now I think I have a better idea.
For example, I am trying to understand the Radon-Nikodym Derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). Here is what I understand:
Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with probability distribution $f(x)$. I want to modify this random variable in such a way, such that for any given value of $x$, the modified value of $x$ changes by some factor (e.g. small change in denominator results in a certain change in the numerator):
$$\frac{dQ}{dP} = \frac{f_Q(x)}{f_P(x)}$$
However, the problem is that while I get to decide what $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ equals to,  I don't what choice of $f_Q(x)$ will result in this modification (e.g. make sure that the final result is a valid probability distribution function).
If I understand correctly, the Radon-Nikodym Derivative helps us determine properties of this modified probability distribution function, such as its Expected Value and the final formula for this distribution itself:
$$E_Q[Y] = E_P\left[\frac{dQ}{dP} \cdot Y\right]$$
$$f_Q(x) = f_P(x) \cdot \frac{dQ}{dP}$$
I tried to create a sample problem involving the Radon-Nikodym Derivative to test my understanding.
Suppose I have a standard Normal Distribution under measure $P$ and I want to modify it such that under some new measure $Q$, the following relationship is true:
$$f_P(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$$
$$dQ/dP = e^X$$
I can first use the Radon-Nikodym Derivative to find out the probability distribution function under the new measure:
$$f_Q(x) = f_P(x) \cdot \frac{dQ}{dP} = f_P(x) \cdot e^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \cdot e^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{x - x^2/2}$$
I can also use the Radon-Nikodym Derivative to find out the Expected Value of this new probability distribution function:
$$E_Q[Y] = E_P\left[\frac{dQ}{dP} \cdot Y\right]$$
$$E_Q[Y] = E_P[e^X \cdot Y]$$
$$E_Q[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot e^x \cdot f_P(x) \cdot f_P(y) \, dy \, dx$$
$$E_Q[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot e^x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2} \, dy \, dx$$
Is this the correct understanding? Have I correctly understood the concept of Change of Measures?

As a side comment, you might find the 2-volume work Some Modern Mathematics for Physicists and Other Outsiders by Paul Roman useful for your self-studying advanced mathematical topics (not just measure theory) as an engineer, if you can find a copy (maybe try interlibrary loan from a local public or university library). More details about Roman's book is given in this MSE answer.

@ Dave: Thanks for this suggestion! I will check it out!

Based on what I wrote, do you think my understanding of the Radon-Nikodym Derivative is correct?

do you think my understanding of the Radon-Nikodym Derivative is correct --- Sorry, but I haven't dealt with this notion in many years, and I don't have time now (and honestly, the desire) to wade into this at the present time.
